# Phantom map in homotopy and homology exists?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map between finite spectrum such that

1. $\pi_{\ast} (f)=0$. (stable homotopy groups)
2. $H_{\ast}(f)=0$. (Homology with integer coefficients)

Does it imply that $f$ is null homotopic ?

Comment: Big open problem

Comment: @FernandoMuro I thought it was an open problem (generating hypothesis) if we assume only that $\pi_{\ast}(f)=0$...

Comment: AFAIK, the question is equally open even for finite spectra with homologies concentrated in non-overlapping degrees.